# Storing dynamic value in mongoDB which refers to other properties

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mean-stack

I am working in Node js - mongoDB . I have a requirement where I need to store and retrieve data in mongoDB which are dynamic and refers to other keys in the collection.
Example:
firstName : string
lastName : string,
fullName : string

Assume we insert a record like below

{
firstName : "hello",
lastName : "world",
fullName : " firstName lastName"
}

Now when we retrieve the record the fullName field is expected to show the actual name . In front end , we could use something like string interpolation to achieve this in angular. Is there any way I can directly handle this expression in backend . My actual use case involves more complex structures hence it is not possible to rely on front end.

Answer (score 0):

Mongo aggregations can be used to do this :

```
let userProps = await users.aggregate([
  {$match: {_id: ObjectId(_id)}},
  {$unset : ["unusedProps"]},
  {$addFields:{fullName: { $concat: [ "$firstName", " - ", "$lastName" ] }}}
])
```

This will return a document with a fullName field.

Mongo aggregation can be used to make way more complex queries with the amount of operators builded in =)

Comment: Thanks for answering. But my challenge is the field is also dynamic in nature, in the sense it doesn't always have same formula to populate. Imagine the field name as action . As this is a collection , based on the query params we may need to return multiple actions. Example 10 actions are returned. Now some of them can be static text. Some needs to be populated based on other fields with different contexts. Is this achievable ?

Comment: I tried but I don't really understand your use case... Could you give a pseudo code example in your question please?